# How to merge and create subsets in a for loop (R)?

Tags: r

I want to optimize this code in a for loop for a bigger set of data.

```
library(reshape2)
Customer<- c("Susan","Louis", "Frank","Susan")
Seller<- c("Ivan", "Donald","Chris","Ivan")
Service<-c("COU","CAR", "FCL","CAR")
Billingmean<- c(100,200,300,400)
WrsHoldSum<-c(0,0,0,0)
Group<- c("n1","n2"," "," ")
B1<- c(0,2,2,1) 
B2<-c(9,8,7,6)
B3<- c(5,4,3,2)
df<- data.frame(Customer, Seller,Service, Billingmean,WrsHoldSum, Group,B1,B2,B3)
sub1<- dcast(data= df, formula= Customer+Group+Seller+WrsHoldSum~Service,fun.aggregate= sum,value.var= "Billingmean")
sub2<- dcast(data= df, formula= Customer+Group+Seller+WrsHoldSum~Service,fun.aggregate= sum,value.var= "B1") 
sub3<- dcast(data= df, formula= Customer+Group+Seller+WrsHoldSum~Service,fun.aggregate= sum,value.var= "B2")
sub4<- dcast(data= df, formula= Customer+Group+Seller+WrsHoldSum~Service,fun.aggregate= sum,value.var= "B3")

finaldf<- merge (sub1,sub2, sub3, sub4,by=c("Customer","Group","Seller","WrsHoldSum"))
```

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would help

Comment: I uploaded an image, if that is helpful for you. Thanks

Comment: Maybe it is, but it's much better to have a short input mimicking your real issue, that we can actually load in R, and the output you'd like to get from it.

Comment: Sorry I'm new in the community. Where do I upload my r code?

Comment: Please read this page on how to make a great R example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1. Don't upload your code: paste the smallest amount needed to show what you want to do into a properly formatted code block in your question.

Comment: Don't worry about all 100 datasets and 305 columns: make a minimal example with 2 datasets and 3 columns (or something small like that). If we can get that to work the way you want it to, scaling it up will be trivial.

Comment: ready..........

Comment: It's much better Diego, your desired output is not very clear however, do you want to get a data.frame with 4 rows and 19 columns ?

Comment: in this case every new subset only adds 3 new columns. Those 3 new columns i want to merge them on a bigger database. Here I only made it for 4 records. I want to do it for longer sets of data.

Comment: Hello @Moody_Mudskipper I need to convert the output from JdM below to a dataframe but I can't do it. I tried as.data.frame() funtion but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

Since you also want to know the origin of the columns that were not part of the `by` argument in `merge`, you can name those columns before `Reduce()` using `lapply` which will conveniently output a list and shorten your `Reduce()` statement:

Identify the name of the tables for `lapply()`:

```
tNames <- grep(x = ls(), pattern = "^sub", value = T)
```

Then use `lapply()` with a custom function that will output the tables with the relevant columns' names already modified. Use the pipe `%>%` for convenience to `Reduce()` the list with `merge()`:

```
lapply(seq_along(tNames), function(x){
  tSym <- as.name(tNames[[x]])
  
  d1 <- copy(eval(tSym))
  
  cols <- grep(x = names(d1), pattern = "^CAR|^COU|^FCL", value = T)
  
  setnames(d1, old = cols, new = paste0(cols, " B", x))
  
  return(d1)
  
}) %>% Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = c("Customer","Group","Seller","WrsHoldSum")), .)
```

Result:

```
  Customer Group Seller WrsHoldSum CAR B1 COU B1 FCL B1 CAR B2 COU B2 FCL B2 CAR B3 COU B3 FCL B3 CAR B4 COU B4 FCL B4
1    Frank        Chris          0      0      0    300      0      0      2      0      0      7      0      0      3
2    Louis    n2 Donald          0    200      0      0      2      0      0      8      0      0      4      0      0
3    Susan         Ivan          0    400      0      0      1      0      0      6      0      0      2      0      0
4    Susan    n1   Ivan          0      0    100      0      0      0      0      0      9      0      0      5      0
```

Comment: I allowed myself to edit your post following OP's changes in the question, I hope it's fine

Comment: I want an output just like this but I would like to identify which columns were merged from B1, B2, B3 etc.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Isn't B* summarized in the previous `dcast()` step?

Comment: Yeah that's right, but I want to see which columns of CAR, COU, FCL, belong to each dcast(). I don't want to see duplicates over the name columns. I want something like CAR B1, COU B1, FCL B1, CAR B2, COU B2, FCL B2... just to know from where the combination came from.

Comment: OK, you could've mentioned this in your question. You can try this: `library(magrittr); Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = c("Customer","Group","Seller","WrsHoldSum")), list(sub1,sub2, sub3, sub4)) %>% setnames(., old = grep(x = names(.), pattern = "^CAR|^COU|^FCL", value = T), 
         new = paste0(grep(x = names(.), pattern = "^CAR|^COU|^FCL", value = T), rep(paste0(".B", seq_along(list(sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4))), each = 3)))`

Comment: replace this part then `new = paste0(substr(grep(x = names(.), pattern = "^CAR|^COU|^FCL", value = T), 1, 3)`

Comment: it still shows me an error message. "column names ‘CAR.x’, ‘COU.x’, ‘FCL.x’, ‘CAR.y’, ‘COU.y’, ‘FCL.y’ " are duplicated in the resultHow could I optimize my code for a larger quantity of subs?

Comment: @DiegoCastillo No worries. Don't forget to upvote and check the answer as correct. Some ppl may have a similar question to you in the future. Cheers

Comment: Hey @JdM, now everything is running ok. Just a final request, i need to export this table into a csv. and view it as a dataframe in R. Now I'm only able to see it as a table format. I tried ´as.data.frame ()´ but it didn't work.

Comment: do you need to export into csv or import a csv table?